# Send multiple key values in Authorization header

Tags: http, http-headers, bearer-token

If you use 'Bearer' for the Authorization header can you also send other parameters/values in the Authorization header?

Just bearer looks like (where 12345 is the token)

> Authorization: Bearer 12345

But can you also pass other Authorization info?

> Authorization: Bearer 12345, Other=6789

Answer (score -2):

No, you can't. You can only send credentials for a single challenge. See RFC 7235.

Comment: Sure but each scheme can have multiple parameters right?

Comment: Only those that use params in credentials, which is not the case for Bearer. See <http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7235.html#considerations.for.new.authentication.schemes>, item 3.